# Elastic 8.5.3 is not starting

Tags: windows, elasticsearch, installation

After I used elastic 8.2 successful I delete it, also the elasticsearch folder in *C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp*, than I downloaded the current version 8.5.3 and start the bin/elasticsearch.bat. On the end I **don't get the password and fingerprint and I can't reach via *https://localhost:9200/*** .

I'm using the current version of Java.
I restart the computer.

The [console text I linked on my private page](https://mehlhop.com/forum/console.txt) and
the log file you [find here](https://mehlhop.com/forum/elasticsearch.log), because it is to long for this forum. (It will both open in your Browser.)

At the log is a Memory error. But I got around 22 GB free RAM.
Further there is a *"exception during geoip databases update"*. But I think this is not important, also because I don't need the geo locations.

**What could be the reason that it is not proper installing elasticsearch on my device** (Windows 11)**?**

Comment: `[2023-01-09T13:53:45,620][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [FM11L] current.health="GREEN" message="Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [GREEN] (reason: [shards started [[.geoip_databases][0]]])." previous.health="RED" reason="shards started [[.geoip_databases][0]]` means Elasticsearch is up and running without any issues

Comment: you can ignore the geoip error as it resolved itself and is not critical

Comment: `[2023-01-09T13:46:50,583][INFO ][o.e.x.s.Security         ] [FM11L] Security is enabled
[2023-01-09T13:46:53,971][WARN ][o.e.b.BootstrapChecks    ] [FM11L] Transport SSL must be enabled if security is enabled. Please set [xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled] to [true] or disable security by setting [xpack.security.enabled] to [false]`
Revisit SSL settings of your node(s) and configure them as per the documentation: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/secure-cluster.html